# Notice bar at frontpage for multisite

Tags: multisite, notifications

Running a multisite install I would like to distribute messages to all sites as a top notice bar on frontpage. All sites are read and posted from frontpage so admin area message plugins won't work.

Searched and can't find plugin/solution that works for both communicating with all sites on multisite and not at adminarea. Also, I'm not using the WP admin bar on front for this network, so that is not an option. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean you've hidden the admin bar, or you don't want a solution using the admin bar?

Comment: I've disabled the adminbar because I don't want it in this network.

Comment: Good to know - are you using a global theme, or does each site have its own?

Comment: Same theme on every site. Modified P2

Comment: Below plugins have the functionality, only I want One to Many.<br/>
  
  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/take-notice
  
  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-notices

Comment: Wanted linebreaks in comment above but did not work my way..

Comment: If you're using the same theme, you can just add some html/css/js into the theme itself - google "top bar javascript" for a number of suggestions on how best to make it work.  I'm not really sure on the process of converting a single-site plugin to multisite - if I can figure it out, I'll let you know.

Comment: _Afaik:_ Just network activate it or use a mu-plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use the adminbar on front. Plus you can customize it to your needs.

### Example on how to add a node

```
// Read here 1)
function nacin_promote_network_admin_in_toolbar( $wp_admin_bar ) {
    $wp_admin_bar->add_node( array(
        'id' => 'network-admin',
        'parent' => false,
    ) );
}
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'nacin_promote_network_admin_in_toolbar', 25 );
```

<sup>1) Read on WPDevel how to [`add/remove_node`s in the admin bar](http://wpdevel.wordpress.com/2011/12/07/admin-bar-api-changes-in-3-3/).</sup>

Comment: Ok, that can definitely be usefull for for future dev, but for this one I'm not using adminbar. Thank's!